# How implement longPressGestureRecognizer for subview with disabled user interaction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, swift, uikit

I need UI like this:

[image]

with 2 buttons (yellow and red) and background view (grey), which will have next behaviour:
- highlight button when i press on it;
- execute when i release on button;
- when i press and move in on button from any other view, button became highlighted (ex: press on grey rect and release on red, or press on yellow and release on red);
- support gestures for buttons (like long press and swipe)

So for solving my problem i found only next way:
I redefine for my `GrayView` touch methods: `touchesCancelled`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesBegan`, and there are i check if current touch position is belong to some rect - i execute appropriate action. But for this solution i have to make my buttons with `userInteractionEnabled = false`, which means they doesn't support gestures or other events anymore. So if i what to use support it, i have to implement it by myself, what i don't what to do.

So how can i solve this?

Comment: What did you do to detect that button is pressed (before your first solution) ? is it a gesture ? UIView methods overriding ? button action touch down ?
Can't give you help with so few informations about your implementation

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you can add the gesture recognizers to the gray view as well. And when the gesture recognizer fires find which colored view was in the touch area:

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        CGPoint position = [recognizer locationInView:grayView];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(redView.frame, position) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're are right, but it's help only for long press or tap, but for swipe gesture it's not very helpful, or am I wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do when user swiped?

Comment: You still should be able to find which view was swiped. I'm not sure if you even need to do the locationInView, what is logged if you display recognizer.view in console ?